# How to set a property of a non-pointed object in C++/CLI

Tags: pointers, c++-cli

Here is the header of a class with a property in C++/CLI :

```
    public ref class MyClass
    {
       public:
         property double x
         {
            double get();
            void set(double value);
         }

         MyClass();
     }
```

If I use a pointer to instantiate the object I can set the `x` property like this :

```
MyClass^ obj = gcnew MyClass();
obj->x = 10.0;
```

If I do not use a pointer, then I have a compilation error 
(C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union) using this code :

```
MyClass obj();
obj.x = 10.0;
```

What should I do for the second example ?

Is this syntax issue specific to properties or to any member of a non-pointed object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just got trapped by the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse):

```
MyClass obj();
```

This *does not* define a variable `obj` of type `MyClass`. If declares a *function* `obj` that takes no parameter and returns `MyClass`.

Just write this instead:

```
MyClass obj;
obj.x = 10.0;
```

Or this:

```
MyClass obj{};
obj.x = 10.0;
```

Both compile just fine.

`obj` uses [stack semantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177191.aspx) despite the fact that `MyClass` does not implement `IDisposable` (ie has no `~MyClass` member in C++/CLI).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess i'll have to go deeper in my (little) understanding of C++. :)

Answer (score 0):

The second syntax is called stack semantics. It creates the object and "destroys" it, when the variable gets out of scope.

In fact not the memory is freed, but Dispose is called for the object.

So the second syntax using a period instead of the pointer operator -> is only valid vor objects with stack semantics.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177191.aspx